# What's the best way to determine if a variable is a particular object?

Tags: php, oop, instanceof

I recently read about the difference between `is_a()` and `instanceof`
I am currently using `get_class` to do an object comparison.  I read that `is_a` was deprecated but brought back by popular demand even though `instanceof` is slightly faster.  When would you decide to use each of these variants and why not use one of the others instead?

```
if (get_class($var) == 'MyObject')

if ($var instanceof \MyObject)

if (is_a($var, \MyObject))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you really want to check.

**get_class** check will tell you if given object is of given class. **instanceof**  operator on the other hand will tell you, if given object is of given class OR has that class in it's inheritance tree OR implements given interface.

Some examples:

```
class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent {}

$obj = new Child;

var_dump($obj instanceof Parent); // true
var_dump(get_class($obj) === 'Parent'); // false
var_dump($obj instanceof Child); // true
var_dump(get_class($obj) === 'Child'); // true
```

So both ways can be used depending on what you need.

Regarding **is_a()**, it behaves the same way as **instanceof** operator, but is know to be a bit slower. In bigger applications the difference in performance will be negligible.

**instanceof** offers more flexibility. While **is_a()** only accepts string as its second argument, **instanceof** can be passed a string, an object or class identifier.

Answer (score 1):

A fourth option is:

If you have control over the object definition, then add a public property to your parent class definition named `public $_myquirkyparentproperty = true;`, then use `isset($var->_myquirkyparentproperty)`.  This is the fastest object identification in PHP, when you have control over the objects.  Add different properties to your parent and child classes, and continue to use isset() to differentiate them.

Here's a benchmark (->_srf_object is my personal object property), and $a is my object:

```
 MIN: time ratio (500x), fastest times (least interference)
 [1."(isset($a->_srf_object))"] => 1.00x    (5.006790161132812E-6)
 [2."(get_class($a))"] => 2.62x (1.311302185058594E-5)
```

Make sure to name the property something that won't collide with other classes' properties.  Maybe your name.